# progress bar python pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, progress-bar

Умные головы, подскажите как правильно задать значения прогресс бару, при делении видео на кадры получается 700+ кадров например, значение cnt со 100 кадров сразу заполняет прогресс бар на 100.
здесь я пытаюсь задать прогресс бар:

```
for i in range(len(video_colors)):
        video_colors[i] |= image_bits[i]

    video_colors = np.reshape(np.asarray(video_colors), (req_frame_count, vid_height, vid_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    # create dirs
    if os.path.exists("temp"):
        remove_directory_content("temp")
    else:
        make_dir("temp")

    cnt = 1

    for frame in video_colors:
        cv2.imwrite('./temp/frame{:09d}.png'.format(cnt), frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
        cnt += 1

    print('Starting write back...')
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite('./temp/frame{:09d}.png'.format(cnt), frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
            cnt += 1
            w.progressBar.setValue(cnt)  # progressbar
        else:
            break
```

ПОЛНЫЙ КОД:

```
def hide(carrier_video, image_message):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(carrier_video)
    msg = cv2.imread(image_message)

    vid_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    vid_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    vid_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    # count = 0
    # TIME_LIMIT=100

    req_frame_count = required_frame_count(cap, msg)

    bin_rep_width = bin_rep(msg.shape[1]).zfill(16)

    bin_rep_height = bin_rep(msg.shape[0]).zfill(16)

    bin_rep_mult = bin_rep(msg.shape[0] * msg.shape[1]).zfill(32)

    image_bits = [int(x == '1') for x in bin_rep_width + bin_rep_height + bin_rep_mult]

    for row in msg:
        for column in row:
            for color in column:
                for i in range(8):
                    image_bits.append(int((color & (1 << (7 - i))) != 0))

    video_colors = []

    for i in range(req_frame_count):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            raise Exception('Error in extracting video frames')

        for row in frame:
            for column in row:
                for color in range(3):
                    video_colors.append(column[color])

    assert len(video_colors) >= len(image_bits)
    for i in range(len(video_colors) - len(image_bits)):
        image_bits.append(0)

    video_colors = [(color & 0xFE) for color in video_colors]

    for i in range(len(video_colors)):
        video_colors[i] |= image_bits[i]

    video_colors = np.reshape(np.asarray(video_colors), (req_frame_count, vid_height, vid_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    # create dirs
    if os.path.exists("temp"):
        remove_directory_content("temp")
    else:
        make_dir("temp")

    cnt = 1

    for frame in video_colors:
        cv2.imwrite('./temp/frame{:09d}.png'.format(cnt), frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
        cnt += 1

    print('Starting write back...')
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite('./temp/frame{:09d}.png'.format(cnt), frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
            cnt += 1
            w.progressBar.setValue(cnt)  # progressbar
        else:
            break
```

Comment: joparez228, то что вы предоставили не очень похоже на минимально-воспроизводимый пример. Меня также смущает нахождение строки `w.progressBar.setValue(cnt)` в цикле `while True:`.

Comment: Ну прогресс бар заполняется пока идет цикл разбивания видео на кадры, я установил w.progressBar.setMaximum(700) все гуд, может вы подскажите мне метод который очищает прогресс бар после заполнения ?

Comment: joparez228  `w.progressBar.setValue(0)`

Comment: joparez228 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#reset

Answer (score 1):

по коду не вполне ясно, но что мешает

```
w.progressBar.setMaximum(700) # или сколько вам надо
```

и устанавливайте cnt 100-200-300... прогрессбар проценты сам подсчитает

Comment: а какой метод очищает прогресс бар после заполнения полоски?

Comment: reset() - откат на нули, setMaximum(0) - будет бегающая полоска типа "ожидание"

Answer (score 0):

Вот алгоритм прогресс бара. Какую число вы не писали он всегда показывает выполнения прогресса в проценте.

```
def bp():
input_integer = int((ui.lineEdit.text()))
a = 0
while a <= input_integer:       
    x = 100 / input_integer
    x = x * a       
    a = a + 1
    ui.progressBar.setValue(x)
```